# Canonical Isomorphisms in Commutative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $M,N$ be abelian groups, and let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $S$ be a multiplicatively closed subset of $R$, with $1\in S$.

> 1) Suppose that $M,N$ are $S^{-1}R$-modules. Is it true that if I have an $S^{-1}R$-isomorphism $f:M\to N$ then it is also an $R$-isomorphism? (here actually I do not need to assume that $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules, since I think I can give them an $R$-module structure here below).

This seems true to me since I can define the action of $R$ on $M$ and $N$ by $r\cdot m=\frac r 1m,r\cdot n=\frac r 1 n$ for every $m\in M$ and $n\in N$. Hence $f(r\cdot m)=f(\frac r 1 \cdot m)=\frac r 1 f(m)=r\cdot f(m)$. Morphism and bijectivity hold anyway.

> 2) The converse of (1) is false I think. However, consider the well-known fact: Let $M$ be an $R$-module. Then $S^{-1}M$ is isomorphic to $M\otimes_R S^{-1}R$. But are they isomorphic only as $R$-modules or (more strongly) as $S^{-1}R$-modules and then you deduce also as $R$-modules by (1)?

If you look at the proof, you see that you constructed two $R$-isomorphisms $\phi:S^{-1}M\to M\otimes_RS^{-1}R$ given by $m/s\mapsto m\otimes 1/s$ and $\psi: M\otimes_R S^{-1}R\to S^{-1}M$ given by $m\otimes a/s\mapsto am/s$.

Now on $S^{-1}M$ you have the natural structure as $S^{-1}R$-module, but also on $M\otimes_R S^{-1}R$ you can define an $S^{-1}R$-module structure by defining the action $\frac {r} {s} \cdot (m\otimes_R \frac t u)=m\otimes_R \frac {rt} {su} $.

> 3) Is this $S^{-1}R$-module structure correct? In this way do the above maps $\phi$ and $\psi$ become $S^{-1}R$-isomorphisms too?

Comment: For 1), how can you have a $S^{-1}R$-isomorphism? $M$ and $N$ are not  $S^{-1}R$-modules.

Comment: In your hypotheses, you should say then  ‘Let $M$ be  an $S^{-1}R$-module’, &c.

Comment: @user26857 I edited it. Thank you. By the way, do you have a complete answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For point 2), you have this result:

> If $M,N$ are two $S^{-1}R$-modules, the canonical homomorphism
>   $$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}\Hom_{S^{-1}R}(M,N)\longrightarrow\Hom_R(M,N)$$
>   is an isomorphism.

(Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, ch. II, *Rings and modules of fractions*, §2 n°8, prop. 19.)

Indeed, if $f$ is an $S^{-1}R$-linear, it is also $R$-linear by restriction of scalars.  So the canonical homomorphism is injective (it is the inclusion morphism).

Conversely, any $R$-linear map $f\colon M\longrightarrow N$ is also  $S^{-1}R$-linear since for any $s\in S$ and  any $m\in M$, $f(m)=f\bigl(s\,\frac ms\bigr)=sf\bigl(\frac ms\bigr)$, whence $\;f\bigl(\frac ms\bigr)=\frac{f(m)}{s}$, and more generally
$$f\Bigl(\frac as \,m\Bigr)=f\Bigl(\frac {am} s\Bigr)=\frac{f(am)}s=\frac{af(m)}s=\frac asf(m).$$

Comment: How does the inverse map work? How can you turn a general $R-morphism$ into an $S^{-1}R-morphism$?

Comment: Tensoring with the identity of $S^{-1}R$.It works  because $M$ and $N$ are not *any* $R$-modules, but modules for which multiplication by an element of $S$ is an isomorphism. From this property, you deduce that any $R$-homomorphism is *ipso facto* an $S^{-1}R$-homomorphism.

Comment: ok but this is too general for me. I can't see it in my problem. I would like to know just if my comments are correct or not.

Comment: They're correct, since, as I said, $R$-linear for $S^{-1}R$-modules implies  $S^{-1}R$-linear.

Comment: But in my construction I gave an $S^{-1}R$ structure by hand for which I hope $\psi$ and $\phi$ became $S^{-1}R-isomorphisms$ and I can't see that what I have done is the thing that you are claiming, namely tensoring with the identity

Comment: $\psi$ and $\phi$ are indeed isomorphisms reciprocal to each other. For the isomorphism I mention in my answer, I don't really need to tensor with identity, it's only for the sake of compatibility with $\phi$ and $\psi$

Comment: But could you prove me in a direct way that if I have an $R-morphism$, say $f$, between $S^{-1}R-modules$, then it is automatically an $S^{-1}R-morphism$? And could you prove me that this is what I have done in my comment without knowing this more general fact? thank you

Comment: I've added a proof of the assertion. This is what was missing in what you've done, which results from standard facts about the identification of modules of fractions with tensoring with the ring of frcations.

Comment: ok thank you. Finally, do you confirm that the $S^{-1}R-module$ structure that I gave to $M\otimes_R S^{-1}R$ is correct? After this I can mark your answer

Comment: It's perfectly correct for me.